# I want the wordpress post image to have the post link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to Wordpress
I am implementing a custom theme that is derived from the parent theme tewnty twelve.
I want something like bellow:
I am uploading media that will be inserted inside the post. We know that when we click on the post title, it takes us to the full post page. But when i click on the image inside the post, it takes me to the url like this: www.mohin.com/?attachement_id=10 which i don't want. I want the image click takes me to the full post page as the title click does.
Is there anyone who can help me on this issue

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
mohin

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's pretty straightforward. Just select the image in your post editing window, select the hyperlink icon, and paste the URL you want the link to go to. Update and then check. When clicking the image it should go to that link.

Comment: Hi Barbara, thanks but I don't want to do it manually. I have written a child theme of twenty twelve and I want my theme to do that. So I will only add the post and upload the image and publish it. The code should put the url as the href of image link.
Lets say the post url is: www.xyz.com/?p=120
So, the image tag should be exactly same we see when we add the image url manually like:
<a =href="www.xyz.com/?p=120">
  <img src="image source" />
</a>
So, basically i want my code to do my job instead of doing it manually
Hope that help to understand my need